Cannot rsync to a remote server, while cp works
I want to transfer a file from a local machine to a mounted remote server drive using rsync, however I get the following error:
rsync -ahP ./fastp.html /server/folder1/nobackup/user/metagenomics/analysis

sending incremental file list
fastp.html
         32,77K   6%    0,00kB/s    0:00:00  rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/server/folder1/nobackup/user/metagenomics/analysis/.fastp.html.wKvWKq" failed: No such file or directory (2)
        492,75K 100%  438,67MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.3.0]

If I run cp ./fastp.html /server/folder1/nobackup/user/metagenomics/analysisthe file is copied properly. If I rsync to other another mounted remote directory, it works just fine.
Other topics suggest another rsync instance running (ran killall rsync), or non-static files, but that is not the case here.
Also there should be no issues with the connection, as cp works fine and I can just access the mounted server drive in my explorer.
Do you have any ideas about how to solve this? I'd prefer rsync over cp as it involves many large data files. rclone copy does work. Why would rsync not work in this case?

Seems like the mount protocol or the underlying file system has issues with the file or filename of that temporary file. What is the mount type? Can you use nfs or sshfs or even ssh directly?

the mount type is cifs

For people that experience this in the future: It appeared to be related to permission on this particular server. Adding --temp-dir=/tmp to the command works.
